# Connections pool in Go mgo package

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

In the article [running-mongodb-queries-concurrently-with-go](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/80579086742/running-mongodb-queries-concurrently-with-go) said that        mgo.DialWithInfo     : Create a session which maintains a pool of socket connections to MongoDB, but when I looking for in the [documentacion](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo) of the function [DialWithInfo](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#DialWithInfo) I do not find something that talk me about pool connection, only I find something in the [Dial](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Dial) Function Dial Function that said : This method is generally called just once for a given cluster. Further sessions to the same cluster are then established using the New or Copy methods on the obtained session. This will make them share the underlying cluster, and manage the pool of connections appropriately.

- Can someone say me how works the pool connections on MGO and if is possible set up this pool?
- Is it true that DialWithInfo create a Pool Connection or is only the Dial function that create this pool?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 10):

Looking into the [source code for the Dial function calls](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/session.go#L195), you can see that the `Dial` function calls the `DialWithTimeout` function which calls the `DialWithInfo` function. So to answer your question about the differences between the functions, it seems like `Dial` is a convenience wrapper for `DialWithTimeout`, which in turn is a convenience wrapper for `DialWithInfo`, so they result in the same connection pool.

As to how to manage that connection pool, you've got it right in your question.

> Further sessions to the same cluster are then established using the New or Copy methods on the obtained session. This will make them share the underlying cluster, and manage the pool of connections appropriately.

So a single call to `Dial` or `DialWithTimeout` or `DialWithInfo` will establish the connection pool, if you require more than one session, use the `session.New()` or `session.Copy()` methods to obtain it from the session returned from whichever Dial function you chose to use.

Comment: However, `.Copy()` should be used since it retains authentication, if applicable.