# Golang Database Connection Pool with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, connection-pooling

In the past few days I have been making some tests scenarios on a performance test project, where I have a combination of golang + mongodb and the results where really impressive, however, when you send a multiple request, the performance drops dramatically and I guess the problem because there is no connection pooling(maybe?), I am a java developer and the mongodb java driver for mongodb has implicitly a connection pool.

So is there a connection pooling or I have ti create one on my own ?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223743/connections-pool-in-mgo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the performance drops dramatically and *I guess* the problem because there is no connection pooling (*maybe*?)

[Profile](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) and ye shall succeed. Wild guesses will only waste your time.

Read also: [Connections pool in Go mgo package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223743/connections-pool-in-mgo)

If you're using the amazing [`mgo`](https://labix.org/mgo) driver, then you have auto-managed connection pooling built-in.

Answer (score 3):

At the current time (2020-01-29), according to MongoDB-GO-Driver official standard which was NOT documented publicly, the official driver itself will maintain a connection pool, you just need to set the pool size (min&max).

The referrence can be found at: [Official GitHub Repo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/data/connection-monitoring-and-pooling/connection-monitoring-and-pooling.rst)

BTW, `mgo` seems not actively maintained.